# How do I return the system date or datetime in DB2 for Z/OS?

Tags: sql, db2, zos

How do I return the system date or datetime in DB2 for Z/OS using SQL?  I am more familiar with SQL Server, where I would use "SELECT getdate()".  I've tried a few permutations of this on DB2, but with no luck so far.  Seems like I need a predicate, but am not sure where system information would be "FROM".  Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try select current date from sysibm.sysdummy1

Comment: Shouldn't that be `current_date` (with an underscore?)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It works with either on DB2. (same with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` vs `CURRENT TIMESTAMP`)

Comment: *current_date* actually did not work in my environment.  Could be driver-specific.  I'm using StarSQL JDBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, try:

```
values(current timestamp)
```

Comment: Is one of these methods more efficient than the other?